# Use Dictionary for Table Data show in swift 4

Tags: swift3

I am using Alomofier in my code and data show in tableview but my dataArray getting nil value

```
my struct:-

   struct sizeData 
{

 var sizevalue = String()

 var sizeing = [[String:Any]]()

  }
```

Create Array :-

```
var dataArray : [sizeData] = []
```

my json:-

```
                    func productDetailsApi() {

                        let param: [String:Any] = ["product_id" : product?.product_id ?? "", "token": commonClass.sharedInstance.userToken ?? "" ]
                        print(param)
                        //printD("param: \(param)")

                        Alamofire.request(ShopConstants.ShopAPI.Shopurl("productDetails"), method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
                            (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
                            let json = response.result.value
                            printD(json)
                             let Json = json as! [String:Any]
                            printD(Json)

                             let status = Json["status"] as! Int
                            if status == 1 {
                                let data = Json["data"] as! [String:Any]
                                  let product_detail = data["product_detail"] as! [String:Any]
                               printD(product_detail)
                                 let sizes = data["sizes"] as! [[String:Any]]
                                for item in sizes{
                                    let getsize = item["sizes"]as! String
                                    self.dataArray.append(sizeData(sizevalue: getsize, sizeing: sizes))
                                }
                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            }
                        }

                    }

                tableView:-  

                 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                        return dataArray.count
                    }

                    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SizelistCell")as!
                        SizelistCell
                        cell.sizeLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].sizevalue
                        return cell
                    }

                }

    my response:-

    my json:-

        {
            "status": 1,
            "data": {
                "product_detail": {
                    "id": 35588,
                    "name": "relaxo",
                    "alias": "relaxo",
                    "release_date": "2019-01-31 12:01:00",
                    "images": null,
                    "description": "Lorem ispum   lorem ispum Lorem ispum   lorem ispum Lorem ispum   lorem ispum",
                    "sku": "rel-1200",
                    "style_code": "rel-1200",
                    "original_price": "",
                    "offer_price": {
                        "min_price": 100,
                        "offer_price": 100,
                        "color": "red",
                        "size": "10",
                        "stock": 2,
                        "sold": 0,
                        "original_price": 120
                    },
                    "is_offer": 0,
                    "hero_image": null,
                    "available_at": null,
                    "url": null,
                    "release_day": null,
                    "release_month": null,
                    "brand_id": 117,
                    "store_id": 24,
                    "hero_image_url": "",
                    "hero_image_id": null,
                    "release_date_pretty": null,
                    "original_price_pretty": "",
                    "hero_image_alt": null,
                    "canonical_url": null,
                    "merchant_name": null,
                    "shipping_policy": null,
                    "style": null,
                    "scrap_from": null,
                    "meta_title": "",
                    "meta_keywords": "",
                    "meta_description": "",
                    "is_server": 0,
                    "is_top_sale": 0,
                    "is_most_viewed": 0,
                    "product_type": "women",
                    "status": 1,
                    "is_deleted": 0,
                    "date_updated": "",
                    "date_created": "",
                    "created_at": "2019-02-02 07:06:34",
                    "updated_at": "2019-07-08 06:00:01",
                    "slide_images": [],
                    "available_qty": 2,
                    "ColorData": {
                        "min_price": 100,
                        "offer_price": 100,
                        "color": "red",
                        "size": "10",
                        "stock": 2,
                        "sold": 0,
                        "original_price": 120
                    },
                    "sizes": [
                        {
                            "sizes": "10"
                        }
                    ],
                    "colorset": "red",
                    "colors": [
                        {
                            "color": "red"
                        }
                    ],
                    "average": null,
                    "count": 0
                },
                "policy": {
                    "id": 30828,
                    "product_id": 35588,
                    "meta_key": "policy_config",
                    "meta_value": "{\"warranty_policy\":\"Yes\",\"return_policy\":\"No\",\"delivery_policy\":\"Yes\",\"cancellation_policy\":\"Yes\"}",
                    "created_at": "2019-02-02 07:06:35",
                    "updated_at": "2019-02-02 07:06:35"
                },
                "policy_details": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "type": "delivery_policy",
                        "description": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.</p>",
                        "status": 1,
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "updated_at": "2019-01-19 08:16:12",
                        "created_at": "2019-01-19 07:40:03"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "type": "warranty_policy",
                        "description": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.</p>",
                        "status": 1,
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "updated_at": "2019-01-19 11:57:31",
                        "created_at": "2019-01-19 07:40:03"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "type": "cancellation_policy",
                        "description": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla augue nec est tristique auctor. Donec non est at libero vulputate rutrum. Morbi ornare lectus quis justo gravida semper. Nulla tellus mi, vulputate adipiscing cursus eu, suscipit id nulla.<br /><br />Pellentesque aliquet, sem eget laoreet ultrices, ipsum metus feugiat sem, quis fermentum turpis eros eget velit. Donec ac tempus ante. Fusce ultricies massa massa. Fusce aliquam, purus eget sagittis vulputate, sapien libero hendrerit est, sed commodo augue nisi non neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor, lorem et placerat vestibulum, metus nisi posuere nisl, in accumsan elit odio quis mi. Cras neque metus, consequat et blandit et, luctus a nunc. Etiam gravida vehicula tellus, in imperdiet ligula euismod eget.</p>",
                        "status": 1,
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "updated_at": "2019-01-19 11:57:31",
                        "created_at": "2019-01-19 07:40:03"
                    }
                ],
                "brandSizeInches": {
                    "cm": [
                        "10",
                        "10",
                        "10"
                    ],
                    "us": [
                        "10",
                        "10",
                        "10"
                    ],
                    "uk": [
                        "10",
                        "10",
                        "10"
                    ],
                    "inches": [
                        "10",
                        "10",
                        "10"
                    ],
                    "euro": [
                        "11",
                        "11",
                        "11"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "msg": "Product Details found successfully"
        }
```

How do I fetch data in sizes[[String:Any]] and show size value in  tableview cell......

Comment: The parent of `sizes` is `product_detail` not `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching sizes from data instead its part of product_detail

```
   Alamofire.request(ShopConstants.ShopAPI.Shopurl("productDetails"), method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
                            (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
                            let json = response.result.value
                            printD(json)
                             let Json = json as! [String:Any]
                            printD(Json)

                             let status = Json["status"] as! Int
                            if status == 1 {
                                let data = Json["data"] as! [String:Any]
                                  let product_detail = data["product_detail"] as! [String:Any]
                               printD(product_detail)
                                 let sizes = product_detail["sizes"] as! [[String:Any]]
                                for item in sizes{
                                    let getsize = item["sizes"]as! String
                                    self.dataArray.append(sizeData(sizevalue: getsize, sizeing: sizes))
                                }
                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            }
                        }
```